# Understanding the proof of completeness of $L^1$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I'm reading the proof of completeness of $L^1 (X, \mathscr{M}, \mu)$, and I would like to clear up some confusion

To prove $L^1$ is complete it suffices to show that every Cauchy sequence $(f_n)$ has a convergent subsequence, so assume wlog that

$$\| f_{n+1} - f_{n}\| \le 2^{-n}$$

and consider the series

$$f_1 + \sum_{i=1}^m f_{i+1} - f_{i}$$

This is bounded by

$$|f_1||  + \sum_{i=1}^m |f_{i+1} - f_{i}|$$

Setting $g_m = \sum_{i=1}^m |f_{i+1} - f_{i}|$ we have $g_m$ converges up to $g$, and $g \in L^1$.  Furtheremore, $f_1 + \sum f_{i+1} - f_{i}$ converges to $f \in L_1$.  Since the preceding series is bounded by $|f_1| + G$, the dominated convergence implies
$\|f_n - f\| \to 0$ in $L^1$ norm.

**My questions**

Why does $g_m$ converge to $g \in L^1$.  Why does this implie that $f_1 + \sum f_{i+1} - f_{i}$ converges?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an outline: $g_m$ converges pointwise, since it is an increasing sequence of functions. The limit is in $L^1$ by the monotone convergence theorem (MCT): For if $g_m\to g$ pointwise, MCT gives $\|g\|_1=\int g\,d\mu=\lim\int g_m\,d\mu\le \sum_k 2^{-k}=1$.
The convergence is not only pointwise, but in $L^1$, since $\|g-g_m\|=\int(g-g_m)\,d\mu\to0$.

It follows that $g<\infty$ a.e., and therefore $\sum(f_{i+1}-f_j)$ converges absolutely a.e. (by the very definition of absolute convergence). In particular, it converges pointwise a.e. to some limit. Applying the triangle inequality to tails of the sum should lead to a proof of $L^1$ convergence.

(**Edited** to add some detail.)

Comment: My question is why does convergence of $g_m$ point wise and in $L^1$ to $g$ implies convergence of $\sum f_{i+1} - f_i$.

Comment: Nevermind, I guess functions in $L^1$ are by definition $X \to \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: If $g = \lim g_n$.   I wonder why $g$ is guaranteed to be in $L^1$, since the point wise limit could be $\infty$.

Comment: The answer to your last question is: The integral of $g$ is finite by the monotone convergence theorem, and in particular, the pointwise limit is finite a.e. But it may well be infinite at some points. I added some detail to my answer.